# Doctrine dynamic Schema migration

Tags: symfony, doctrine, migration

I'm currently facing an issue in migration with doctrine and my multiple database (db_name)

---

I have inside the same MYSQL instance multiple database, one for the company and the other for each Client (Entity).

Each database is created inside the postPersit operation (i'm running a custom command that override the database:create of doctrine to create a database with the uuid of the client, this is working).

I want to do the same with the migration but I'm facing an error "config not found" and when I put the general configuration, it do not found what it needs.

I created a WrapperConnection and added the possibility to select the database. I'm using this wrapper before running an API platform request  (inside an ApiNormalizer).

My code ...

```php
#[AsCommand(name: 'custom:migration:migrate')]
final class MigrationCommand extends DoctrineCommand
{
    use EntityManagerTrait;
    use ParameterBagTrait;

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setAliases(['migrate'])
            ->setDescription(
                'Execute a migration to a specified version or the latest available version.',
            )
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'The database name'
            )
        ;

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $databaseName = $input->getArgument('name');

        if (null === $databaseName) {
            // return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        /** @var MultiDbConnectionWrapper */
        $connection = $this->em->getConnection();
        $connection->selectDatabase($databaseName);
        
        // Doctrine code is below.

        $migrateCmd = new DoctrineMigrateCommand($this->getDependencyFactory());

        $migrateInput = new ArrayInput([
            '--configuration' => $this->parameterBag->get('kernel.project_dir').'/config/packages/doctrine.yaml',
        ]);

        $migrateCmd->run($migrateInput, $output);
     }
}
```

I tried to copy/past directly the code of the class to edit it... I failed ...

I want to use the migration on dynamic schema but I'm new on doctrine code and migration.
Can u help me ?

---

If I knew how the config is working, I could have created copies of the migration files with the good schema I think and run it ...  what do you think ?

Sorry for my approximative english.

Answer (score 0):

I found it.

Here is the solution

```php
<?php

namespace App\Command\Doctrine;

use App\Service\Trait\EntityManagerTrait;
use App\Doctrine\MultiDbConnectionWrapper;
use App\Service\Trait\ParameterBagTrait;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputArgument;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArrayInput;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\NoMigrationsFoundWithCriteria;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\NoMigrationsToExecute;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Exception\UnknownMigrationVersion;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Metadata\ExecutedMigrationsList;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\ConsoleInputMigratorConfigurationFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Formatter\OutputFormatter;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputOption;
use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\DoctrineCommand;
use Doctrine\Migrations\DependencyFactory;

use Doctrine\Migrations\Tools\Console\Command\MigrateCommand as DoctrineMigrateCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;

// the name of the command is what users type after "php bin/console"
#[AsCommand(name: 'alx:migration:migrate')]
final class MigrationCommand extends DoctrineCommand
{
    use EntityManagerTrait;
    use ParameterBagTrait;

    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setAliases(['migrate'])
            ->setDescription(
                'Execute a migration to a specified version or the latest available version.',
            )
            ->addArgument(
                'name',
                InputArgument::REQUIRED,
                'The database name'
            )
        ;

        parent::configure();
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        $databaseName = $input->getArgument('name');

        if (null === $databaseName) {
            // return Command::FAILURE;
        }

        // These two file are generated for temporary use.
     
        $dbFilePath = $this->getTmpDatabaseFile($databaseName);
        $migrationFilePath = $this->getTmpDatabaseFile();


        $migrateCmd = new DoctrineMigrateCommand();
        $migrateCmd->setName('doctrine:migrations:migrate');
        $migrateInput = new ArrayInput([
            '--db-configuration' => $dbFilePath,
            '--configuration' => $migrationFilePath
        ]);

        $migrateCmd->run($migrateInput, $output);

      
        return 0;
    }
}
```

the db file

```php
<?php 

return [
    'url' => 'mysql://USER:PWD@database:3306/myDatabaseName?serverVersion=10.5.15-MariaDB&charset=utf8mb4'
];
```

The migration file (yaml)

```yaml
migrations_paths:
        # namespace is arbitrary but should be different from App\Migrations
        # as migrations classes should NOT be autoloaded
        'DoctrineMigrations': '/app/migrations'
table_storage:
  table_name: 'doctrine_migration_versions'
  version_column_name: 'version'
  version_column_length: '191'
```